# Why does spin acting along $x$ on the spin up state yield spin down?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, quantum-spin

I'm currently struggling on how to interpret the particular result below:

$$\hat{S}_{x}\ | \alpha \rangle \ = \frac{\hbar}{2}\ | \beta\rangle$$

Where $\ | \alpha \rangle \ $ is the spin up state and $\ | \beta \rangle \ $ is the spin down state. After some reading, as I understand, spin up is conventionally along the positive z axis. What I'm stuggling to understand is why applying $\hat{S}_{x}$ to $\ | \alpha \rangle \ $ yields $\ | \beta \rangle \ $ from an intuitive perspective beyond just plugging in the  for $\hat{S}_{x}$ and working through.

An idea I have is that the left hand side is representative of measuring spin up along the x axis and since these are not in the same direction $\ | \alpha \rangle \ $ is not an eigenfunction of $\hat{S}_{x}$ hence we don't get an associated eigenvalue equation? Second is that this measurement perturbs the system changing the state of spin?

I'm also not quite sure as to what the Pauli matrices are representative of in this equation. Given that

$$\hat{S}_{x} = \frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} =\frac{\hbar}{2} \sigma_{x} $$

is there any physical reason (or coincidence) for the Pauli matrix to look like a reflection in the line y=x and does this help with explaining my confusion with the initial result.

I'm still very new to studying quantum mechanics so please forgive any mistakes or incorrect/"silly" reasoning I may have.

Comment: why alpha and beta? What's wrong with MathJax arrows?

Comment: Just the notation my lecturer used

Answer (score 6):

> ...What I'm stuggling to understand is why applying $\hat{S}_{x}$ to $\ | \alpha \rangle \ $ yields $\ | \beta \rangle \ $ from an intuitive perspective beyond just plugging in the  for $\hat{S}_{x}$ and working through.
> ...
> $$\hat{S}_{x} = \frac{\hbar}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
> 0 & 1\\ 
> 1 & 0
> \end{pmatrix} =\frac{\hbar}{2} \sigma_{x} $$
>
> is there any physical reason (or coincidence) for the Pauli matrix to look like a reflection in the line y=x and does this help with explaining my confusion with the initial result.

You could take the physical meaning of angular momentum to be that it is the generator of rotations. (Explained by example below.) You could also take angular momentum to mean the thing that is conserved due to rotational invariance. (Similar to how linear momentum is conserved in translationally invariant systems.)

For spin 1/2 particles, the $S_x$ operator you wrote down is the generator of rotations about the $x$-axis:
$$
R_x(\theta) \equiv e^{-i\theta S_x} = \cos(\theta/2) - iS_x\sin(\theta/2)\;,
$$
so, a rotation by $\pi$ about the $x$-axis is effected by simply:
$$
-iS_x\;,
$$
and indeed, such a rotation rotates a $+z$ eigenstate into a $-z$ eigenstate, and vice versa, as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at it is that $S_x$ is that since
$$
S_x|\alpha\rangle = \frac{\hbar}{2}|\beta\rangle,\\
S_x|\beta\rangle = \frac{\hbar}{2}|\alpha\rangle,
$$
then
$$
S_x\left(|\alpha\rangle \pm |\beta\rangle\right)=\frac{\hbar}{2}\left(|\beta\rangle \pm |\alpha\rangle\right) = \pm \frac{\hbar}{2}\left(|\alpha\rangle \pm |\beta\rangle\right)
$$
that is the eigenfucntions of $S_x$ are superpositions, with equal weights, of spin-up and spin-down states (in respect to z-axis) - they are neither up, nor down.

(Similar reasoning of course applies to $S_y$, as well as to considering action of $S_y$ in the eigenbasis of $S_x$ - I propose working through it yourself.)